# navigation drawer activity and i see only ".WelcomeActivity"?

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest

I make project in (navigation drawer activity) and I show only `WelcomeActivity`.
Where do I put the intent-filter ?

So I can only see .WelcomeActivity

```xml
<activity
    android:name=".RegistrationActivity"
        android:exported="false" />
<activity
    android:name=".LoginActivity"
    android:exported="false" />
<activity
    android:name=".WelcomeActivity"
    android:exported="false" />
    
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:exported="true"
    android:label="My Food App"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyFoodApp.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: Kindly ask your question clearly, I could not understand what's the problem and what you want to achieve.

Comment: Hi @Tejas Patel and welcome to Stack Overflow. As @Kamal Nayan just stated above me, you'll have to add more information to you question if you want anyone to be able to help you. For example, how are you trying to open `WelcomeActivity`? :-)